# How to get direct index value of array post

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

How to get direct values for array post

> [store_image] => Array ( [delete] => 1 [value] =>
>   test/1/test.jpg
>   )

I am using this to get the value of check box

```
if ($main_images=$this->getRequest()->getPost('store_image')) 
    { 
      $delete=$main_images['delete'];
    }
```

but if check box is not checked it gives me **Notice**

> Notice: Undefined index: delete

How to prevent from this notice **Magento way**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your code like this:

```
$delete = array_key_exists('delete', $main_images) ? $main_images['delete'] : false;
```